# How to get impala queries

Tags: impala, cloudera-manager

I need to monitor and statistic impala history queries.

Cloudera manager UI can get impala history queries.

Does impala has any restful api to get history queries?

Answer (score 2):

On my cluster, `$MYMACHINE:25000/queries` has a list of queries.

Comment: tks, but this be compelx!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it sure does:  http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/

A lot of the bugs of this API have gotten worked out over the last few releases.

I am guessing the specific get() you will want will come from here:

[http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/path__clusters_-clusterName-*services*-serviceName-_impalaQueries.html](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_impalaQueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

CDH has its own REST METRICS API (the same used for Cloudera Charts):

- e.g. Total Queries Across Impala Daemons: http://CDH_MGMT_HOST:7180/api/v6/timeseries?query=select+total_num_queries_rate_across_impalads+where+entityName%3D%22impala%22&contentType=application%2Fjson
- Official CDH documentation: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cm_metrics_impala_daemon.html